# Removing a DE field when DE is used in a data relationship

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I have a Data Extension field I'd like to delete, but that DE is used in an attribute group/set in Contact Builder. So is it really necessary to delete the data relationship first before I can remove the field? Seems too risky if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, seems you have to remove the relationship first. Otherwise, you can't delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it turns out you need to delete the relationship first, so removing a field of that data extension is possible.

Answer (score 7):

It is indeed possible to remove a field in a linked Data Extension, with a small workaround. Using SOAP, I have successfully removed a field, without unlinking the Data Extension in Data Designer. You need to perform two calls to achieve this:
1: Retrieve details for the data extension in which you want to delete the field. You will need the Object ID of the field later:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">**** Access Token ****</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Filter xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>**** Data Extension External Key ****</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

2: Execute the Delete request, pointing at the Data Extension / Field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">**** Access Token ****</fueloauth>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Delete</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:d5c8c2ee-384e-4492-af18-b01e0d438b62</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://**** Your SOAP Subdomain ****.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <DeleteRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options />
         <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <CustomerKey>**** Data Extension External Key ****</CustomerKey>
            <Fields>
               <Field>
                  <ObjectID>**** Object ID of the field to delete (from first call) ****</ObjectID>
               </Field>
            </Fields>
         </Objects>
      </DeleteRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Don't panic if the field is not removed straight after the code is executed. It can take few minutes, and the values for the field are set to *undefined* for all the records, before the field is removed.

Comment: Skeptical of this, but worked a charm :) I used ObjectID in both cases, so doesn't need to be CustomerKey

Comment: To which address do you send these SOAP messages?