# Delete Attribute Confirmation

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I added a field to a data extension that was linked through the contact model.  Now, I realize that I need to delete that field and add a different field.

This data extension is a primary table that affects a lot of automations & injection into several journeys.

I know that I can unlink, adjust the data fields (in a minimal way) and then relink, but I am unsure of the ramifications of doing so, even if it only takes 3 minutes to make adjustments.

Are there any gotchas to that I need to be aware of before I potentially do irreparable damage to this contact model?

Comment: If the name of the field is changing, any sql references will need to be updated. Otherwise data with either not be displayed in the target data extension or the query will fail.

Comment: Also assuming you are doing any updates in contact builder, as the tool will not allow this in email studio

Comment: @RichardLewis I am referring to a data extension that has been linked to the contact model.  If I want to change the data extension fields in any way I must unlink the data extension through the data designer.  My concern is surrounding what actually occurs when linking and unlinking a DE from the contact data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the data extension from contact model will only affect the use of the DE in Journey Builder (for decision splits and entry filters). Using it in query activities, Ampscript (e.g. Lookup), and as a source DE for JB will not be affected by unlinking it from the contact model - as these features are perfectly able to use an unlinked Data Extension.

If you want to avoid disconnecting the DE, you can use SOAP to remove the field without removing the DE from Data Designer: [Removing a DE field when DE is used in a data relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184378/removing-a-de-field-when-de-is-used-in-a-data-relationship)

Comment: This DE is used pretty heavily in Journey Builder with decision splits based on contact data...if I unlink and relink - will those decision splits still function, or have I changed the contact relationship in salesforce's eyes.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with SOAP, but I have added a link to a previous answer on this topic - where you can remove the field without unlinking the DE.