# Unable to delete an attribute from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

When trying to remove the attribute, I get a pop-up with the text:

> You cannot delete any attributes used in existing data relationships
> before removing those relationships. Use Data Designer to remove those
> relationships before attempting a deletion.

It also states that the Data Extension is linked to 1 population. It is a normal DE by the way, not a synchronized one.

First of all, I don't understand the message. I am not trying to remove a relationship, just an attribute. To do it, I click on the trash can icon on the right hand side of the list of attributes of the Data Extension.

Apparently I need to do something before I can delete an attribute?

I see a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184378/removing-a-de-field-when-de-is-used-in-a-data-relationship), but I do not understand the answers. One uses two SOAP requests? And the other states "Yes, it turns out you need to delete the relationship first, so removing a field of that data extension is possible." But what relationship are we talking about?

Comment: Go to Data Designer and find the Attribute Group(s) in which your DE has been used. The field you are trying to delete must have been used to establish a relationship between your DE and another DE, that’s why it cannot be deleted while in use.

Comment: There are 14 Attribute Group(s), some of them made by MC, some of them made by my company. I have checked all, and the attribute is not used in any of them. Also, it's just a simple boolean attribute, I don't see how it can be used to establish a relationship. I have 7 more of those attributes and none of them can be removed. Do you know how to find out which relationship is meant?

Comment: @zuzannamj - I think is is just enough that the field is in a linked data extension in Data Designer. It doesn't need to be the field used to map the relationship.

Comment: According to the Data Designer, 14 Attributes Group exist, 7 of which have been created by MC itself, such as MobileConnect Data and Chat Message Data. I would have to remove all those relationships and restore them after I have deleted my 8 fields? I need to delete those, because they are going to be deleted from Sales Cloud as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to delete attributes from Synchronized Data Extensions, or regular data extensions?

Comment: I have edited my question. The removal of the fields in Sales Cloud is not making this urgent, as the fields in Sales and Marketing Cloud are not directly connected, but the fields no longer serve any purpose, so I just want to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

After examining all possible relationships in the Data Designer, I have concluded that the relationship to which MC is referring, must be the population relationship.

I have no idea what happens if I delete that, I find conflicting advice on the internet. So I will not delete it, better safe than sorry. Which means that I cannot delete the fields that I want to delete.

My "solution" now: rename the unused attributes to "Available 1" - "Available 8" and change the automation/SQL query that fills the Data Extension, to fill the attributes with empty  values. Anytime that I need to use a new field, I can reuse one of those 8, provided of course it's of the proper type.