# SOAP API to Delete Column from Dataextension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, postman

I'm trying to become better at understanding Marketing Cloud SOAP API.

My goal is to delete a column from a SFMC dataextension from Postman.

Adding columns was easy, as documentation provided a complete SOAP envelope:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/adding_new_column_to_an_existing_data_extension.html

But they don't provide one for deleting columns.
So I looked into the documentation and see that the Dataextension object does support delete method: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.html
However I can only find examples of deleting an entire dataextension, not just a single column.

I'm actually not just seeking a working SOAP envelope, I'm seeking an explanation on how to read and understand the documentation, in order to know, how to do it myself.

I've looked into the documentation for the Dataextension object:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html

and the dataextensionField object:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextensionfield.html

But I just don't know how to interpret it into creating my SOAP Envelope for deleting a column.

**Here is my working example of adding a column to my dataextension**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options /> 
            <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <CustomerKey>{{dataextensionexternalkey}}</CustomerKey> 
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <Name>MyColumnName</Name> 
                        <FieldType>Text</FieldType> 
                        <MaxLength>10</MaxLength>
                        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired> 
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Hope someone is able to help me understand it better.

Comment: Did you see my SOAP payload for the same use case here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/251061/36623

Comment: @LukasLunow Got it to work, I will try to understand how to make sense of the solution from the documentation :-) 
Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome. Remember to upvote the referenced answer if it was helpful